# kineticjs performance lag

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am working on a radial control similar to the HTML5 wheel of fortune example. I've modified the original here with an example of some additional functionality I require: http://jsfiddle.net/fEm9P/ When you click on the inner kinetic wedges they will shrink and expand within the larger wedges. Unfortunately when I rotate the wheel it lags behind the pointer. It's not too bad here but it's really noticeable on a mobile.

I know this is due to the fact that I'm not caching the wheel. When I do cache the wheel (uncomment lines 239-249) the inner wedges no longer respond to mouse/touch but the response on rotation is perfect. I have also tried adding the inner wedges to a separate layer and caching the main wheel only. I then rotate the inner wheel with the outer one. Doing it this way is a little better but still not viable on mobile.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Stephen

```
  //constants
  var MAX_ANGULAR_VELOCITY = 360 * 5;
  var NUM_WEDGES = 25;
  var WHEEL_RADIUS = 410;
  var ANGULAR_FRICTION = 0.2;

  // globals
  var angularVelocity = 360;
  var lastRotation = 0;
  var controlled = false;
  var target, activeWedge, stage, layer, wheel, 
      pointer, pointerTween, startRotation, startX, startY;
  var currentVolume, action;

  function purifyColor(color) {
    var randIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
    color[randIndex] = 0;
    return color;
  }
  function getRandomColor() {
    var r = 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 55);
    var g = 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 55);
    var b = 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 55);
    var color = [r, g, b];
    color = purifyColor(color);
    color = purifyColor(color);

    return color;
  }
  function bind() {
    wheel.on('mousedown', function(evt) {
      var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
      angularVelocity = 0;
      controlled = true;
      target = evt.targetNode;
      startRotation = this.rotation();
      startX = mousePos.x;
      startY = mousePos.y;
    });
    // add listeners to container
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      controlled = false;
        action = null;
      if(angularVelocity > MAX_ANGULAR_VELOCITY) {
        angularVelocity = MAX_ANGULAR_VELOCITY;
      }
      else if(angularVelocity < -1 * MAX_ANGULAR_VELOCITY) {
        angularVelocity = -1 * MAX_ANGULAR_VELOCITY;
      }

      angularVelocities = [];
    }, false);

    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
      var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
      var x1, y1;
      if(action == 'increase') {
            x1 = (mousePos.x-(stage.getWidth() / 2));
            y1 = (mousePos.y-WHEEL_RADIUS+20);
            var r = Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1);
            if (r>500){
                r=500;
            } else if (r<100){
                r=100;
            };          
            currentVolume.setRadius(r);
            layer.draw();            
      } else {  
          if(controlled && mousePos && target) {
            x1 = mousePos.x - wheel.x();
            y1 = mousePos.y - wheel.y();
            var x2 = startX - wheel.x();
            var y2 = startY - wheel.y();
            var angle1 = Math.atan(y1 / x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
            var angle2 = Math.atan(y2 / x2) * 180 / Math.PI;
            var angleDiff = angle2 - angle1;

            if ((x1 < 0 && x2 >=0) || (x2 < 0 && x1 >=0)) {
              angleDiff += 180;
            }

            wheel.setRotation(startRotation - angleDiff);
          }
      };
    }, false);
  }
  function getRandomReward() {
    var mainDigit = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    return mainDigit + '\n0\n0';
  }
  function addWedge(n) {
    var s = getRandomColor();
    var reward = getRandomReward();
    var r = s[0];
    var g = s[1];
    var b = s[2];
    var angle = 360 / NUM_WEDGES;

    var endColor = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
    r += 100;
    g += 100;
    b += 100;

    var startColor = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';

    var wedge = new Kinetic.Group({
      rotation: n * 360 / NUM_WEDGES,
    });

    var wedgeBackground = new Kinetic.Wedge({
      radius: WHEEL_RADIUS,
      angle: angle,
      fillRadialGradientStartRadius: 0,
      fillRadialGradientEndRadius: WHEEL_RADIUS,
      fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, startColor, 1, endColor],
      fill: '#64e9f8',
      fillPriority: 'radial-gradient',
      stroke: '#ccc',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      rotation: (90 + angle/2) * -1
    });

    wedge.add(wedgeBackground);

    var text = new Kinetic.Text({
      text: reward,
      fontFamily: 'Calibri',
      fontSize: 50,
      fill: 'white',
      align: 'center',
      stroke: 'yellow',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      listening: false

    });

    text.offsetX(text.width()/2);
    text.offsetY(WHEEL_RADIUS - 15);

    wedge.add(text);
    volume = createVolumeControl(angle, endColor);
    wedge.add(volume);

    wheel.add(wedge);
  }

  var activeWedge;

function createVolumeControl(angle, colour){
    var volume = new Kinetic.Wedge({
        radius: 100,
        angle: angle,
        fill: colour,
        stroke: '#000000',
        rotation: (90 + angle/2) * -1
    });

    volume.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
        currentVolume = this;
        action='increase';
    });
    return volume;
}



  function animate(frame) {
    // wheel
    var angularVelocityChange = angularVelocity * frame.timeDiff * (1 - ANGULAR_FRICTION) / 1000;
    angularVelocity -= angularVelocityChange;

    if(controlled) {
      angularVelocity = ((wheel.getRotation() - lastRotation) * 1000 / frame.timeDiff);
    }
    else {
      wheel.rotate(frame.timeDiff * angularVelocity / 1000);
    }
    lastRotation = wheel.getRotation();

    // pointer
    var intersectedWedge = layer.getIntersection({x: stage.width()/2, y: 50});

    if (intersectedWedge && (!activeWedge || activeWedge._id !== intersectedWedge._id)) {
      pointerTween.reset();
      pointerTween.play();
      activeWedge = intersectedWedge; 
    }
  }

  function init() {
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 578,
      height: 500
    });
    layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    wheel = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
      y: WHEEL_RADIUS + 20
    });

    for(var n = 0; n < NUM_WEDGES; n++) {
      addWedge(n);
    }
    pointer = new Kinetic.Wedge({
      fillRadialGradientStartPoint: 0,
      fillRadialGradientStartRadius: 0,
      fillRadialGradientEndPoint: 0,
      fillRadialGradientEndRadius: 30,
      fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, 'white', 1, 'red'],
      stroke: 'white',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      lineJoin: 'round',
      angle: 30,
      radius: 30,
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
      y: 20,
      rotation: -105,
      shadowColor: 'black',
      shadowOffset: {x:3,y:3},
      shadowBlur: 2,
      shadowOpacity: 0.5
    });

    // add components to the stage
    layer.add(wheel);
    layer.add(pointer);
    stage.add(layer);

    pointerTween = new Kinetic.Tween({
      node: pointer,
      duration: 0.1,
      easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut,
      y: 30
    });

    pointerTween.finish();

    var radiusPlus2 = WHEEL_RADIUS + 2;

    wheel.cache({
      x: -1* radiusPlus2,
      y: -1* radiusPlus2,
      width: radiusPlus2 * 2,
      height: radiusPlus2 * 2
    }).offset({
      x: radiusPlus2,
      y: radiusPlus2
    });

    layer.draw();

    // bind events
    bind();

    var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(animate, layer);

    //document.getElementById('debug').appendChild(layer.hitCanvas._canvas);

    // wait one second and then spin the wheel
    setTimeout(function() {
      anim.start();
    }, 1000);
  }
  init();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the FastLayer of the new release 5.1 ? You can't add group on it but with a bit of adaptation I think it can be fine.

Comment: Using here FastLayer in not possible - because objects on FastLayer are not listening for events. Stephen, you said that after cache inner wedges no longer respond to mouse/touch. How they should to respond?

Comment: Ah yes, I should have clarified. If you take a look at the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fEm9P/ and click on an inner wedge (near the centre) with the mouse down slide along the outer wedge and the radius will increase and decrease. I'm tempted to replace it with an anchor element in a slide rule but in the mobile app this looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple of changes to the script which greatly improved the response time. The first was replacing layer.draw() with layer.batchDraw(). As the draw function was being called on each touchmove event it was making the interaction clunky. BatchDraw on the other hand will stack up draw requests internally "limit the number of redraws per second based on the maximum number of frames per second" (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-batch-draw).

The jumping around of the canvas I seeing originally when I cached/cleared the wheel was due to the fact that I wasn't resetting the offset on the wheel when I cleared the cache. 
http://jsfiddle.net/leydar/a7tkA/5

```
wheel.clearCache().offset({
  x: 0,
  y: 0
});
```

I hope this is of benefit to someone else. It's still not perfectly responsive but it's at least going in the right direction.

Stephen